# Node.js + socket.io runs locally with foreman but crashes on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I get the following error when running on heroku:

4-07-26T22:24:01.691178+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

```
2014-07-26T22:24:01.692242+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-07-26T22:24:04.483585+00:00 app[web.1]: 
26)
...
2014-07-26T22:24:04.484066+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-07-26T22:24:04.485813+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-07-26T22:24:04.484057+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-07-26T22:24:04.485806+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-07-26T22:24:04.483677+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-07-26T22:24:04.485808+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/emitter/index.js:6:13)
```

If I use, "heroku labs:enable websockets", I get "No such feature: websockets"

Comment: I have the same error...It seems that works for all except us...When I run "heroku labs:list" doesn't show websockets on the list either.

Comment: Did you find the solution? Could you activate the Websockets on Heroku? I just tried the `heroku lab:enable websockets -a appname` but shows me a message: `No such feature: websockets`. If you find the soulution would be nice to know about that! thx!

Comment: Heroku has enabled websockets by default for all apps created after July 7th. Try the got solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

Heroku can't find an object in your ../emitter/index.js. Some folders of the socket.io modules are "gitignored". (Why?)

It looks like **websockets** are no heroku:labs feature anymore and are **enabled by default**. I ran the socket.io chat example without enabling the labs feature.

### Quick Solution

`git add -A --force` | then commit and deploy